# Kivy installation folder

Tags: 13.04

I try to use the [kivy garden](http://kivy-garden.github.io/) but can not find the installation folder kivy!
If someone could tell me where I could find this folder on ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ok! is in:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy
```